# Get indexes of unique values in a vector

Tags: r, vector, unique, indices

I have a vector like this.

```
filenames <- c("kisyu2_mst.csv", "kisyu3_mst.csv", "kisyu2_mst.csv",
               "kisyu3_mst.csv", "kisyu3_mst.csv")
```

I need to get indices from  filenames vector for each unique value.output look like this

for `"kisyu2_mst.csv"` indices vector `c(1,3)`
for `"kisyu3_mst.csv"` indices vector `c(2,4,5)`

Finally, I need to insert it to a list like this:

```
final <- list("kisyu2_mst.csv" = c(1,3), "kisyu3_mst.csv"=c(2,4,5))
```

How to get the indices of unique value from the vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `split`

```
split(seq_along(filenames), filenames)

#$kisyu2_mst.csv
#[1] 1 3

#$kisyu3_mst.csv
#[1] 2 4 5
```

Comment: This worked.Thank you @Ronak, could you explain what seq_along does here?

Comment: @RajithThennakoon `seq_along` generates a sequence from `1:length(filenames)`

Answer (score 2):

We could try `which`:

```
sapply(unique(filenames), function(i) which(filenames %in% i))
# $kisyu2_mst.csv
# [1] 1 3
# 
# $kisyu3_mst.csv
# [1] 2 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `tapply`

```
tapply(seq_along(filenames), filenames, FUN  = I)
#$kisyu2_mst.csv
#[1] 1 3

#$kisyu3_mst.csv
#[1] 2 4 5
```